# C++: How to set a timeout (not reading input, not threaded)?

Tags: c++, linux, algorithm, timeout

Got a large C++ function in Linux that calls a whole lot of other functions, making up an algorithm. At various points given certain bad inputs, the algorithm can get "stuck" and go on forever. Adding a timeout seems appropriate as all potential "stuck" points cannot be predicted. But despite scouring the Internet for timeout examples I've only found how to apply timeouts when either the thing your timing is a separate thread or it's reading inputs. My code is a single thread and does not modify file descriptors, so not coming up with any luck. Do I basically have no choice but to thread it?

Comment: In the absence of i/o what does "stuck" mean?

Comment: infinite loop I guess

Comment: It's always good to know why code is getting "stuck"... if it is in some loop, you can count iterations and bail when the iterations get too high. If you're solely concerned with time elapsed and using C++11 you can use std::chrono::high_resolution_clock and bail if elapsed is too great. But I'd be more concerned with why it does get "stuck" first !

Comment: Then I suppose you can try a timer e.g. timer_create, etc., but you still have to check within the algorithm for a switch to exit itself.  Set the timer before going in.  This is kind of tailor made for a separate thread that you can cancel though.

Comment: Yes, getting stuck is not good, and I'm definitely putting in a lot of effort toward eliminating that occurring, but given the practically uncountable number of directions of execution, a catch-all bucket is required, because it's unacceptable to ever take longer than a minute.

Comment: Unless you can time until "now" from when you started and exit your calculation loop, you will need a threaded approach.

Comment: How about a large try/catch around all the code in the function, and then create a second function which you call from numerous places in your code... the purpose of the function is to throw an exception if the time elapses?

Comment: Does Linux have any callback (to set a timeout flag) or event setting timer functions that you could check for in the programs main loop?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the situation, actually server applications or embedded applications often run for years in background without stopping. I think one option is to let your program run in background and log to a file(or screen) timely, and, if you really want to stop the program after certain time, you can use timeout command or a script to kill your program after that time, say, timeout 15s your-prog.